# MVC3 - Recommended way to create fields for IEnumerables with Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a form for an entity. One of the members is an IEnumerable of a different type (that also has an IEnumerable member), for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Position> Jobs { get; set; }
}
public class Position
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to find a good example of creating multiple fields in the html, how would I allow to enter more than one position? I think I read somewhere about someone who's cloning that part of the form with jQuery - is that the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post talks about [editing a variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) and may be what you are after.

Comment: Generate ids manually? that's what I didn't like about the client-side cloning solution. By reading the code in the project - it seems like it wouldn't work with `Html.EditorFor` - because there's no foreach on items, EditorFor does that

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Editing a Variable Length List, ASP.NET MVC 3 Style with Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153405/editing-a-variable-length-list-asp-net-mvc-3-style-with-table)

I personnally use an improved version of BeginCollectionItem, but I find it still too complicated when used with child views.
This is a great fail of ASP.NET MVC promises (it should be simple, fluid and powerful).

Comment: My head hurts when I think of doing it with several nested editor templates, the ways I've seen of accomplishing this are far from fluid :\

Comment: This is a great fail, i agree for sure.

Comment: M$ think we will use dynamic grids in full javascript ... fully manually. And they persist in this way. They are mad.

Comment: Ok they wrote a jQuery widget dynamic grid or something like that name. but ... it is not simple as you need to learn it. And you are limited by its features and ui.